# Rails - Saved uuid's length is shorter than 32 characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uuid

I am looking to generate an ID that is not guessable (i.e. long string of random characters).

I am currently using https://github.com/sporkmonger/uuidtools:

app/helpers/uuidhelper.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'uuidtools'
module UuidHelper
  def before_create()
    self.id = UUIDTools::UUID.random_create().to_s
  end
end
```

app/models/mymodel.rb

```
include UuidHelper
```

However, this is not giving me the desired effect, i.e. length is always too short.

Is there a way to use adapt this to force larger values?  Is there another approach that I should be using?

I am currently using SQLite for my development database.  Could this have some effect?

I also assume that I should check if the ID exists already before assigning it to a new instance?

Comment: How long is it? As per the example, it should look like: 984265dc-4200-4f02-ae70-fe4f48964159

Comment: May I ask why you want non-sequential IDs?

Comment: Can't you just append multiple UUID's together until you get the length you want?

Comment: What length of string are you looking for? This tool appears to output a standard UUID of 32 chars. The assumption of UUID is that it is Universally Unique. You would have to inspect the method used to generate this particular UUID to confirm that this is a correct assumption though. It may not hurt to check if you are in doubt.

Comment: I'm getting outputs of 74819, 0, 64, 2, 4672 ... not too good.  I have also got collisions already.

Comment: I am going for a length of 32 characters, preferably hexadecimal.

Comment: "I'm getting outputs of 74819, 0, 64, 2, 4672" Huh?  DGM is correct, UUIDs should look like "984265dc-4200-4f02-ae70-fe4f48964159".  The heat death of the universe should occur long before a collision.  This looks like you're grabbing something other than the actual UUID.  My guess would be that you have the wrong field type for your primary key and the SQLite database driver is being too forgiving instead of yelling at you.

Comment: Correct - that was part of the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the SQLite database that was causing the issue - moved to MySQL database and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
require 'digest/sha1'
#to check if generated id is unique
self.id = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(DateTime.now.to_s)[0..length-1] while (ModelName.find(self.id))
```

where length - desired length of output UUID, also you must check it to be unique( which could be false, if length is too small) and ModelName - name of your model

Comment: I'm getting similar outputs here too e.g. 74819, 0, 64, 2, 4672, 1 and collisions.